# Field Theory Phase Factor vs Anomaly

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, low-dimensional-topology, quantum-field-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1411/1411.0945.pdf) on topological quantum field theories the authors discuss something called the anomaly in section 5.  In [Witten's paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1104178138) on field theory and the Jone's polynomial he discusses something called the phase ambiguity on page 390.  Are the anomaly and the phase ambiguity related?

Edit:  I originally referenced the wrong page and term in Witten's paper.  Fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the "phase ambiguity" in the Witten's paper is the so-called *framing anomaly*; The Witten-Reshetikhin-Turaev invariant gains an extra phase factor once you change the framing of a 3-manifold, but this problem is fixed by using the [canonical 2-framing](https://ac.els-cdn.com/004093839090021B/1-s2.0-004093839090021B-main.pdf?_tid=e8f9abbe-596c-40eb-99a6-fe1420ac6d86&acdnat=1543519231_ff723bb106624d959fbfd33ba5429712).

It seems that in the paper you referenced, the $\theta$ map is a Dehn twist, and the "anomaly" is a sort of framing anomaly in this sense.